# How to pass ref/out function pointer to a function?

Tags: d, dmd

I want to instantiate a function pointer:

```
static void GetProc (out function f) {
    auto full = demangle(f.mangleof);
    auto name = full[full.lastIndexOf('.')+1..$];

    f = cast(typeof(f)) GetProcAddress(hModule,name.toStringz);
}
```

But the compiler won't let me use a function-type variable `(out function f)`. I tried using `Object` but apparently `function` is not an `Object` (how-come??). So, how do I pass a `function` as `ref`/`out` variable (without using `template`/`mixin`, which obscures the code and forces me to add many `typeof` statements...) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no type called `function`. A function must specified the return type and argument type like `int function(double, string)`. If you want to support any kind of function, use a [template](http://dlang.org/template.html#function-templates)

```
static void GetProc(T)(out T f) if (isFunctionPointer!T) 
  ...
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way :-) but what do you mean by "There is no type called `function`" ? there are "function pointers", like: `Object function (int) MyFunc; MyFunc = MyOtherFunc;` isn't it ?

Comment: @Tal: Yes, but the type is `Object function (int)`, not `function`.

Comment: O.k, I see. and is it a `value` or a `reference` type ? it doesn't inherit any other type, in the same way that (e.g.) `class X` inherits `Object` ?

Comment: @Tal: It is a value type, and it doesn't inherit from anything. Inheritence only make sense for classes.

Comment: @Tal, correct. It doesn't inherent from anything. For the most part they have value semantics. You can consider it an opaque value blob or as a pointer to an immutable opaque blob. While technically it's a "pointer to a function" there is nothing (portable) I know of you can do to the de-referenced function.